# Count the number of occurrences of certain choices in models

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-queryset

I have the following models:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    # stuff
class Event(models.Model):
    # stuff
class Award(models.Model):
    award_type_choices = (
        (1, "some string"), # a lot of these
        (2, "some other str"),
    )
    award_type = models.CharField(choices=award_type_choices)
    specific_choices = (
        (1, "some string"), # etc
        # only a few of these, but all of these can be found inside award_type_choices.
    )

    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    recipients = models.ManyToManyField(Team)
```

I'm trying to count/annotate the number of times a `Team` has won an award that fits under the `specific_choices` sequence. I can *filter* the teams that have won an award through this bit of code:

```
reversed_choices = dict((v, k) for k, v in Award.specific_choices)
Team.objects.filter(award__award_type__in=reversed_choices.values())
```

However, I am not sure how I should approach counting these. I have used `Count`, `F`, and `ExpressionWrapper` a little bit before, but not extensively to know how to do this right off the bat.

I figured I could approach it by throwing the same parameters as `filter` into a `Count` object, but as soon as I typed it I realized it wouldn't work, ie:

```
Team.objects.annotate(num_specifics=Count('award__award_type__in=Award.specific_choices'))
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find some Django docs about [Conditional Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation) that helped me solve this.

```
def most_specifics():
    reverse_specs = dict((v, k) for k, v in Award.specific_choices)
    return Team.objects.annotate(
        c=Sum(
            Case(
                When(award__award_type__in=reverse_specs.values(), then=1),
                default=0,
                output_field=PositiveSmallIntegerField(),
            )
        )
    ).order_by('-c')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
choices = Award.specific_choices.all()

c = Team.objects.filter(award__award_type__in=choices).count()
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was clear enough. I'm looking to `annotate` each team with a field that is how many times they have an `Award` that is part of the `specific_choices` field. Additionally, `specific_choices` is just a sequence with `int, str` tuples inside of it. Can't call `all()` on that.

Comment: Then it's  just Team.objects.annotate(num_specifics=c) where c is the returned value from the above stated.

Comment: That doesn't work; AFAIK, you can't put a query inside an annotation. Additionally, what that does is count _how many_ teams have won those specific awards, not how many _each_ has won. I'm looking for the latter.

Comment: If you want Django ORM to encounter your specific_choices make it a model field through declaring it specific_choices = models.ForeignKey(Choice) and somewhere before that Choice to be a model to have at least choice of type models.CharField(max_length....

Answer (score 0):

Following code will find number of choices in certain field of a given model:

```
my_field=Model._meta.get_field('field_name')

length=len(my_field.choices._display_map)
```